# How to see the ground state degeneracy (GSD) from a $BF$ theory in $2+1$ $d$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order

I have seen many times the $BF$ theory has non-trivial ground state degeneracy (typically on torus), but I can not see how the conclusion come out. Recently I found a paper by Hansson, Oganesyan and Sondhi, [Superconductors are topologically ordered](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327) in which the superconductor is described by a Maxwell-$BF$ theory. They have a section of the GSD in a $BF$ theory in $2+1$ $d$. But actually I still have questions to understand it.

The $BF$ theory in $2+1$ $d$ is given by the action
$$
S = \frac{1}{\pi} \int d^3 x \epsilon^{\mu \nu \sigma} b_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} a_{\sigma}, \qquad (1)
$$
where $a_{\mu}$ and $b_{\mu}$ are $U(1)$ gauge fields.
$\mu,\nu,\sigma = 0,x,y$.

Working on $2$-torous, as in the section [IV.A](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327) in Hansson's paper, the $BF$ theory can be written in the form
$$
S = \frac{1}{\pi}\int d^3x[\epsilon^{ij} \dot{a}_i b_j+
a_0 \epsilon^{ij} \partial_i b_j + b_0 \epsilon^{ij} \partial_i a_j],
$$
where $\dot{a} = \partial_0 a$ and $i,j = x,y$.  They interpret $a_0$ and $b_0$ are multipliers for constraints
$\epsilon^{ij} \partial_i b_j = 0$ and $\epsilon^{ij} \partial_i a_j = 0$.
Upon inserting $a_i = \partial_i \Lambda_a + \bar{a}_i/L$
and $b_i = \partial_i \Lambda_b + \bar{b}_i/L$,
where $\Lambda_{a/b}$ are periodic functions on the torus, $\bar{a_i}$ and $\bar{b_i}$ are spatially constant, $L$ denotes the size of the system, the above $BF$ theory reduces to
$$
S = \frac{1}{\pi}\int d^3 x \epsilon^{ij} \dot{\bar{a}}_i \bar{b}_j. \qquad (2)
$$

Then they say from the Eq.(2) one can obtain the commutation relation ( [Eq. (38)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327) in  their paper)
$$
[\bar{a}_x, \frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_y] = i, \quad
[\bar{a}_y,-\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_x] = i. \qquad (3)
$$

Moreover, from the commutation relations Eq. (3), one can have ( [Eq. (39)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327) in  their paper)

$$
A_x B_y + B_y A_x = 0, \quad
A_y B_x + B_x A_y = 0, \qquad (4)
$$
where $A_i = e^{i\bar{a}_i}$ and $B_i = e^{i\bar{b}_i}$.
They claim that relations Eq. (4) indicates a $2\times2 = 4$-fold GSD and "$B_i$ can be interpreted either as measuring the $b$-flux or inserting an $a$-flux."

There are several points that I don't understand.

1. How can I get communication relations Eq. (3) from the action Eq. (2)?
2. Why relations Eq. (4) indicate a $4$-fold GSD?
3. How should I understand the statement "$B_i$ can be interpreted either as measuring the $b$-flux or inserting an $a$-flux."?

I would be very appreciate if anyone can give me some hints or suggest me some relevant references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small comment first: usually people call this theory as a Chern-Simons theory in (2+1)d, while the BF theory usually refers to a similar theory in (3+1)d. But anyways, this naming is not important. The U(1) Chern-Simons theory in (2+1)d is always formulated in the following general form
$$S=\int\frac{\mathrm{i}}{4\pi}K^{IJ} a^I\wedge \mathrm{d}a^J.$$
The action in your Eq. (1) corresponds to the following $K$ matrix
$$K=\left[\begin{matrix}0&2\\2&0\end{matrix}\right],$$
which is a very famous $K$ matrix that corresponds to the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ toric-code topological order (or $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory). The low-energy effective theory for a fully gapped superconductor is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory, simply because the condensation of charge-2 Cooper pair has Higgsed the U(1) gauge structure to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. This is equivalent (and probably better) to say that the superconductor exhibits $\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological order.

Regarding your technical questions, I would recommend Wen and Zee's original [paper (cond-mat/9711223)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9711223) on the topological ground state degeneracy of the Chern-Simons theory, or section 8.2.1 of Wen's book. Your last question is related to the Kitaev [toric-code model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code), which I would suggest Kitaev's original [paper (cond-mat/0506438)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438).

Let me try to briefly answer you questions.

1. From Eq.(2) we known the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{\pi}(\dot{\bar{a}}_x\bar{b}_y-\dot{\bar{a}}_y\bar{b}_x)$, according to classical mechanics, the conjugate momenta of $\bar{a}_x$ and $\bar{a}_y$ are
   $$p_{\bar{a}_x}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\dot{\bar{a}}_x)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_y,\quad  p_{\bar{a}_y}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\dot{\bar{a}}_y)}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_x.$$
   By canonical quantization ($[q,p]=\mathrm{i}$ in quantum mechanics), Eq.(3) simply follows from
   $$[\bar{a}_x,p_{\bar{a}_x}]=[\bar{a}_x,\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_y]=\mathrm{i},\quad [\bar{a}_y,p_{\bar{a}_y}]=[\bar{a}_y,-\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_x]=\mathrm{i}.$$
2. To calculate the ground state degeneracy along this line of though, one need to known that the gauge fields $a$ and $b$ are both **compact** due to the fact that their gauge charges are quantized (see section 6.3 of Wen's book), which means that besides the local gauge transformation, the so-called large gauge transformation is also allowed. On the torus, the large gauge transformation send $\bar{a}_i\to\bar{a}_i+2\pi$ and $\bar{b}_i\to\bar{b}_i+2\pi$. Gauge configurations that are related by the gauge transformation are just different labels of the same physical quantum state, so the large gauge transformation actually imposes the boundary condition on $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$. For example, $|\bar{a}_x\rangle=|\bar{a}_x+2\pi\rangle$ are the same state. So the quantum mechanical wave function is subject to the periodic boundary condition like $\psi(\bar{a}_x)=\psi(\bar{a}_x+2\pi)$, meaning that the momentum $p_{\bar{a}_x}=\frac{1}{\pi}\bar{b}_y$ must be quantized to an integer (recall the momentum quantization formula $\frac{2\pi n}{L}$ with $L=2\pi$), i.e. $\bar{b}_y=n\pi$ (with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$). However by the large gauge transformation $|\bar{b}_y\rangle=|\bar{b}_y+2\pi\rangle$ are also the same state, so $n=0,1$ can only take two values, which corresponds to two eigen states of $\bar{b}_y$, spanning a 2-dim Hilbert space. Repeat the same argument for the other conjugate pair $\bar{a}_y$ and $\bar{b}_x$, one can find another 2-dim Hilbert space. Eventually the ground states Hilbert space is simply the direct product of both 2-dim Hilbert spaces, which contains 4 states in total, hence the 4-fold GSD.
3. You can understand the statement in the same way as you understand the following statement in quantum mechanics: the momentum operator $p$ measures the momentum of a particle, and also generates the coordinate translation. Every quantum mechanical operator has two effects: measuring and operating. If it measures the momentum, it must also operate (or change) the coordinate. Now the relation between $a$-flux and $b$-flux is just like the relation between coordinate and momentum, so any operator that measures $b$-flux must necessarily change the $a$-flux (by inserting the flux of cause), and obviously $B$ is such an operator. In the toric-code model, $A$ and $B$ are also known as the loop operator along the homology basis, which has a clearer geometrical and physical meaning. For more about the loop algebra, you may look at the [paper (1208.4834)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4834) by Barkeshli, Jian and Qi, or the [paper (1208.4109)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4109) by You, Jian and Wen.